# Compress existing XPS document

Tags: c#, .net, xps

I would like to load an existing XPS document and compress it additionally. Looking into MSDN it seems that .NET allows for setting the compression and interleaving however i was unable to find out how to apply those settings to an existing document.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest answer: XPS is simply a zip.

**Manually** you can rename your file from `something.xps` to `something.zip`, extract the contents, recompress the contents at a higher compression level, rename the file back again - you just need to make sure that the zip tool you are using doesn't end up putting everything within a sub-directory within the zip.

Or you could do with **scripting or code**.

If you want to reduce the file even more then have a look at my [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25376/Introduction-to-XPS-Part-1-of-n-of-too-many).

The code attached to it is built around manipulating the output from the "XPS printer driver", however most of the ideas in it should yield a lot of useful options for you to use to compress a file.